# Connecting to Facebook using the C# Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk

My connection code is as follows:

```
String appId = Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId;
var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = appId };
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "response_type", "code" },
    { "display", "popup" },
    { "scope", "email" }
};
var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
```

I am getting the error: cannot convert 'from System.Uri' to 'string' on the last line. Apparently, the GetLoginUrl method returns a type Uri and Redirect requires a string. Is there another way to redirect to a type - Uri?

The example provided by codeplex is "webBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);" but I am not using the webBrowser control. Should I be? Or is there another way?

I found one way to solve this.

Replace the last two lines:

```
var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
```

With

```
var loginUrl = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters));
Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(loginUrl));
```

Converting to HTML and back solves the problem. Note that if you leave the loginUrl HtmlEncoded, Facebook will return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5859

Basically, use this:

```
Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```